# Latest Instructions on creating a cookie log in Firefox

Tags: firefox, logging, cookies

I am trying to run Firefox in cookie-logging mode as described here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Creating_a_Cookie_Log , and
- http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/netlib/cookies/cookie-log.html

However, that page was last modified 09:10, 7 Feb 2008 - (its May 2012 now) and may or may not be out of date.

I followed the instructions and did not manage to get any results in my log file. Before I try, try and try again I'd like to know where I can find the most up-to-date instructions on how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page hasn't been modified in 4 years because the instructions haven't changed, either. I have just verified that putting `NSPR_LOG_MODULES=cookie:4` in the environment works with Firefox 12.0 on Windows XP.

If it does not work for you, it could be that Firefox is not permitted to write to the log file – try telling Firefox to log everything to a console window instead:

```
C:\> set NSPR_LOG_MODULES=cookie:4
C:\> set NSPR_LOG_FILE=     (empty value)
C:\> start firefox -console
```

```
$ export NSPR_LOG_MODULES=cookie:4
$ unset NSPR_LOG_FILE
$ firefox -console
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes you are correct. I tried it again and it worked. I must have done a typo somewere and then I lost confidence in the instructions cos of the warning message at: http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/netlib/cookies/cookie-log.html